# Animating using animate CSS and ng directive in Angular js is not working

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am developing a Website using Angular JS. I want to beautify my website adding animation. I am using [Animate css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) because it has rich built-in animation features. According to [this link](https://divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/angular-1-2-and-animate-css/), I assumed that animate CSS can easily be used with angular js to animate using ng directive.

So I downloaded animate CSS and included in my project. My project has ng animate as well. First I animated only using animate CSS like below.

```
<h1 class="banner-title animated bounce">&lt;Tech Blog /&gt;</h1>
```

It is beautifully animating the element, and it is working. But I want to animate binding with ng directive like in [this link](https://divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/angular-1-2-and-animate-css/). Now I am binding with ng-repeat directive like below.

This is my html

```
<div class="subject-widget" ng-repeat="item in items">
   <h1>{{ item.Title }}</h1>
</div>
```

I am animating them when they enter.

This is my css

```
.subject-widget.ng-enter{
    -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
    -moz-animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
    animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
}
```

But the above code is not working. It is not animating the elements when they enter.

Comment: can you please share some more code? the relevant controller and the subject-widget css before the ng-enter.. also you should know that this ng-enter is connected to an 'enter' action, you don't have a form or a input field at least in this code that you have shared.. please give more data so we can help

Comment: That is all the code. What are u not clear with pls?

Comment: What should trigger the animation? what is item.Title? when is it added? add a fiddle where we can understand the direction you want.. In the link you attached here, there is an input on which the 'enter' triggers an action with animation.. what do you want to do with your html code?

Comment: Angular animation works with directive. As u can see in code, ng-repeat will trigger animation. U need to know nothing about items.

Comment: Angular does not trigger event like jquery.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to achieve here. The ng-repeat in your html is been compiled while construction of the DOM so there is no way you are going to see animation of anything unless you add something dynamically after DOM creation.. Help me understand what you are trying to do here..

Comment: That is the way ngAnimate work.

Comment: Given the above conversation, this might be closable under "unclear": _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking_.